# Webobjects equivalent of join in raw sql

Tags: webobjects

I am relatively new to WebObjects so please bear with me.
   I have two tables whose column values I need to retrieve.
   In raw sql the query would be something like:
       "Select a.value1, b.value1 from a, b where a.key1=b.key1"

How do I do the same in webobjects without using rawSQL?

Comment: For the problem as stated, raw SQL probably is the easiest method. Can you articulate what you're trying to do at a higher level—ideally using the entities, attributes and relationships from your EO Model?

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend that you get the book "learning the wonders".

http://learningthewonders.com

It is a great resource to get you started.

subscribe to this:

https://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/webobjects-dev

the apple list is where the remaining webobjects people communicate.

Ask questions there, you will get great responses and there are people there that can really help.